# How to remove all relations from manytomany?

Tags: django

In one model, I have this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    relations = models.ManyToManyField(OtherModel)
    ....
```

and if I choose:

```
my_object.relations.remove(other_model_object)
```

it works.

How to remove all objects from the relations? `my_object.relations.clean()` is not working.

Comment: .remove() and .clear() will remove the relationships, but they won't actually delete related objects...is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719137/how-do-i-remove-multiple-objects-in-a-manytomany-relationship-based-on-a-filter

Answer (score 88, accepted):

First, you'll need to clear the relationship(s) by using .clear() or .remove(), whichever suits your needs better [according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear).

After that, you'll need to delete the object(s) by using the [YourModel].[delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects)() method.

Comment: for m2m fields `.remove()` will delete the relationship using `QuerySet.delete()`. This should delete the related object I suppose. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @sgauri I don't feel 100% confident, but the behavior I observe is that, when calling `remove`, only the "through" record is deleted, and `other_model_object` is not deleted. I don't think the documentation for `remove` says specifically whether or not `other_model_object` is deleted, like it does for `clear`.

Answer (score 51):

If you need to delete only the relationship for all instance between 2 models then you can do that by accessing the Manager of the relationship table. The m2m relationship table can be accessed via `MyModel.relations.through` so for deleting the relationships it becomes easy:

```
MyModel.relations.through.objects.all().delete()
```

reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Comment: Be careful with this as this will delete all rows in the m2m table as calling through.objects decouple the m2m from MyModel. So you need to do something like `Author.books.through.objects.filter(author_id=author.pk).delete()`

Comment: this was what I was looking for. useful, but not the correct answer.

Comment: Warning! This is really dangerous function as it will delete the entire relationship table!

Answer (score 26):

Use `my_object.relations.clear()`

Answer (score 5):

#### models.py

```py
# consider Author & Book model
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='books')
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc    = models.TextField()
```

Here, we assume that a book have many author & a authors have many book.

> book (M) <------> (M) author

1. now, we find `a book all authors` & some operations

```py
books = Book.objects.all()
if len(books) > 0:
    book = books[0]

    # first book all authors
    first_book_all_authors = book.authors.all()
    
    # clear/remove all authors | (not same as delete)
    book.authors.clear()
    
    # add a author
    new_author = Author.objects.create(name = "Author name: Jhon smith")
    book.authors.add(new_author)

    # add multiple author
    all_authors = Author.objects.all()
    book.authors.set(all_authors)

    # remove a author
    auth1 = Author.objects.filter(pk = 1).first()
    book.authors.remove(auth1) # if auth1 is not None, then it's remove this author
```

2. now, you find `a author all books` & some operations

```py
authors = Author.objects.all()
if len(authors) > 0:
    auth = authors[0]

    # first author all book
    first_author_all_books1 = auth.books.all()   # if set related field name | related_name='books'
    first_author_all_books2 = auth.book_set.all() # if not set related field name | 'modelName'_set.all()
    
    # clear/remove all books | (not same as delete)
    auth.books.clear()
    
    # add a book
    new_book = Book.objects.create(title = "new book", desc="book desc")
    auth.books.add(new_book)

    # add multiple book
    all_books = Book.objects.all()
    auth.books.set(all_books)

    # remove a book
    book = Author.objects.filter(pk = 1).first()
    auth.books.remove(book) # if book is not None, then it's remove this book
```

NB: THINK SIMPLY

Answer (score 4):

To remove **all** related objects without deleting them, just use:

```
my_object.relations.remove(*my_object.relations.all())
```