# Django Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models A and B where

```
class B(Model):
   As = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

Then I do the following

```
a_instance.b_set.clear()
```

in order to remove all references from a_instance to any b_instances. But then I've got the following error:

```
Database Error: column a_b/id doesn not exists
Line 1:  SELECT "a_b"."id",
```

And this is true, my intermediate table a_b in many-to-many relationship (between A and B) doesn't have field named id. It has two other fields instead a_id and b_id.

So does anyone knows how can I force Django to use a_id and b_id instead of just id?

Comment: @btoueg, I took it from documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/. The example they show is p2.article_set.clear(), so it look pretty legitimate for me.

Comment: Indeed! I jumped to conclusion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django requires to have id field in many-to-many relationship table.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete the relationship for one instance between 2 models you can do that by accessing the Manager of the relationship table. The m2m relationship table can be accessed via `MyModel.relations.through` so for deleting the relationships:

```
B.As.through.objects.filter(a=a_instance).delete()
```

reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Credit : [How to remove all relations from manytomany?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230276)

Comment: thanks for clarification, but now I receive exactly the same error I had before - "no id field in the a_b table". Any other ideas of why it might happen?

Comment: It is very strange that your intermediary table does not have an `id` column. Just checked on my db and it should. Have you tried customizing this table through Django? Or maybe directly with SQL?