# Django remove multiple m2m relations without loop

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I am trying to find the most efficient way to remove a single m2m relation from many objects in a queryset. For example, lets say I have 3 model classes to create a messaging system - profiles, threads that link multiple profiles together, and posts that are linked to a single thread and keep track of which profiles have not read the post yet.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   # stuff here

class Thread(models.Model):
   profiles = models.ManyToManyField('Profile')

class Post(models.Model):
   thread = models.ForeignKey('Thread')
   not_seen_by = models.ManyToManyField('Profile')
```

Given a profile:

```
prof = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
```

A thread:

```
thrd = Thread.objects.get(id=thread_id)
```

And a queryset with all the posts to the thread:

```
msgs = Post.objects.filter(thread=thrd)
```

What is the most efficient way to remove the profile `prof` from the field `not_seen_by` in all `Post` objects in `msgs`?

The most straightforward way to do it would be to loop through all the objects:

```
for m in msgs:
    m.not_seen_by.remove(prof)
```

But this doesn't seem very efficient - `prof` may or may not be in `not_seen_by`. It would be much easier to be able to call a method on the queryset itself - somethings like `msgs.not_seen_by.remove(prof)`. Is there any method that allows for anything like this? If so, would it even be more efficient, or would it essentially be shorthand code for running the loop?

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230276/how-to-remove-all-relations-from-manytomany), but using `Post.not_seen_by.through.objects` only allows filters through `id`, `post`, and `profile`, so I wont be able to limit the `remove` operation to only those `Posts` that are linked to thread `thrd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my **View you can Limit The deletion to Posts of a specific thread**.

Like this

```
Post.not_seen_by.through.objects.filter(post__thread=t, profile=prof).delete()
```

Please tell if I am wrong..

If this Doesn't work than you can always write **Raw Queries** using `.raw` in Django. Then use SQL's magic to do this. :) ;)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest making the intermediate model explicit, and then using its manager directly:

```
class Profile(models.Model): 
    # stuff here

class Thread(models.Model): 
    profiles = models.ManyToManyField('Profile') 

class Post(models.Model): 
    thread = models.ForeignKey('Thread') 
    not_seen_by = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', through='NotSeenBy')

class NotSeenBy(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile')

prof = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
thrd = Thread.objects.get(id=thread_id)
NotSeenBy.objects.filter(post__thread=thrd, profile=prof).delete()
```