# Looping over all objects and removing object where ids match?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a number of Lists where each List contains a number of Users, and I would like to remove a certain user from all Lists.

I was trying to do this in my views.py but it is not workin and I'm not sure why. I started looping through all lists, for each list check if the user belongs to that list, remove the user from the list. Otherwise just set a message. Here is my code for this:

```
def delUserFromList(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)

    for list_id in List.objects.all() :
         if user.user_lists.filter(pk=list_id).exists():
            list_id.user.remove(user)
            message = "Success!"
         else:
            message = "User does not exist on this list!"
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is it not ok that for each list I check whether the user has that list and then remove?

Thanks for the help!

Edit:
I was missing `from list.models import List` in my views.py file.

Comment: Why the "javascript" tag?

Comment: Try changing `if user.user_lists.filter(pk=list_id).exists():` to `if user.user_lists.filter(pk=list_id.pk).exists():` .

Comment: @nick I just figured it out, issue was that I was not importing the List model in my views.py :(. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @nnnnnn my bad, copy/pasted from a previous question, no JS involved this time

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230276/how-to-remove-all-relations-from-manytomany#comment29784270_13364368):

```
def del_user_from_lists(user):
    user.user_lists.through.objects.filter(user_id=user.pk).delete()
```